# How to make session valid for a certain amount of hours

Tags: php, session, cookies, zend-framework

So in this zend 1 application, when I go to start page, I can see that there is a cookie named `PHPSESSID`.
I then log in (a custom login) and the user can go through protected pages.
But if he is inactive for more than 30 minutes, when then requesting a protected page the application will redirect him to login page.

What I was focusin on was the `PHPSESSID`. Which initially was set to 30 minutes. I increased that by adding "28800" to what seems to be a global call to `setcookie`.

When I then reloaded the page, I could see that `PHPSESSID` would expire after 8 hours.
Despite this, the use is still being logged out after 30 minutes.
So changing cookie expiration didn't gave anything.
What's next? Changing the php session duration?
Current relevant values are:

```
session.cache_expire: 180
session.gc_divisor: 1000
session.entropy_length:32
session.gc_maxlifetime: 14400
session.gc_probability:1
session.name: PHPSESSID
```

Or is this related to the framework itself? Somewhere in Zend to adjust the expiration of the session?

Comment: Probably you are setting "setExpirationSeconds" for Zend_Session_Namespace somewhere in your code to 30 mins. Try to find it and change it to 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using zend then try this.

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $authns = new Zend_Session_Namespace($auth->getStorage()->getNamespace());
    $authns->setExpirationSeconds(60 * 30); //expire auth storage after 30 min
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple php site storing session files in the same dir - php gc processes may have different set for session. In this case store session files in another, only for you site, directory.